# python assign more than one string to a variable ?how to run this code?

Tags: python, while-loop

so im newbie here , im trying to write a program for a theater ticketing system.
this is just me trying to find out how to use while , so i can stop the program from taking the next step if the input is wrong  , here is the while code:( i got it some where and i changed some stuff)

```
Movie_is = "a"# i want to assign more than one string like "A","b","B" etc
movie_slection = True

while movie_slection:
Choose=raw_input("Choose your movie by typing the correct letter")
if Choose != Movie_is:
    print 'Wrong input'
    movie_slection = False 
elif Choose == Movie_is:
    print 'Your movie is :'

else:
print 'Wrong input.'


print 'Done'</i>
```

and this is the other  code that i want to use the 1st code in it , if i type d it goes to the tickets selection  :

```
print "a.Fight Club (1999)", "b.Freaks (1932)","c.Barton Fink (1992)"

Movie_is=raw_input("Choose your movie by typing the correct letter")
if Movie_is == "a" or Movie_is== "A":
 movie = "Fight Club (1999)"
elif Movie_is == "b" or Movie_is=="B":
 movie = "Freaks(1932)"
elif Movie_is == "c"  or Movie_is== "C":
 movie = "Barton Fink (1992)"
else:
 movie = "You have entered a wrong letter ,\n note:this application is case sensitive"
print " Selected Movie : ", movie

# the tickets selection
Tickets_is=raw_input(" Select Tickets: a.(Adult) b.(Children) c.(Senior) d.(Student)")
if Tickets_is=="a" or Tickets_is== "A"  :  
tickets="""
    ||       SCREEN         ||

     1 2 3 4 5 6 7 8 9 10


  """

elif Tickets_is == "b" or Tickets_is=="B":
 tickets= """
    ||       SCREEN         ||

     1 2 3 4 5 6 7 8 9 10


  """
elif Tickets_is == "c" or Tickets_is== "C":
 tickets= """
    ||       SCREEN         ||

     1 2 3 4 5 6 7 8 9 10


  """
elif Tickets_is == "d" or Tickets_is== "D":
 tickets= """
    ||       SCREEN         ||

     1 2 3 4 5 6 7 8 9 10


  """

else:
 tickets= "You have entered a wrong input , please type a valid seat number"
print "Seats: ",tickets </i>
```

Thanks in advance .

Comment: Then you problably want to use a `list` of strings instead of a simple string.

Comment: Your indentation is a mess. This is a problem in Python and makes it hard to tell what your code sample is supposed to mean.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You will want to use a list instead of a string:

```
movies = [ 'a', 'b', 'c' ]
for movie in movies:
    print movie
```

But you probably want a [class](http://docs.python.org/2/tutorial/classes.html) to define a movie. That allows you to collect all information about a single movie in one place.

Comment: thanks ! I'll start learning about classes and hopefully i find my answer .

Answer (score 0):

You will need to look at Python lists. Something like this

```
movie_is = ['a', 'b', 'c']
if choice not in movie_is:
    print 'Wrong input'
```

See http://docs.python.org/2/tutorial/datastructures.html for more on lists

Comment: hmm, lists and classes ..i guess i have some stuff to learn today , thanks

Answer (score 0):

You want something like this?:

```
>>> choose = "a"
>>> movie_names = ["A", "a"]

>>> choose in movie_names
True
```

Comment: sorry i really dont understand how to use this code , a newbie here .. thanks anyway

Answer (score 0):

A [dictionary](http://docs.python.org/2/tutorial/datastructures.html#dictionaries) would be far more useful than the method you are currently using. I won't modify the script to do a while loop as you desire, but you should be able to convert this over easily enough.

```
movies={'a':'Movie A','b':Movie B'}
if choice.lower() is not in movies.keys():
     print 'Invalid choice. Try again'
else:
     print 'You have selected '+movies[tolower(choice)]
```

As is said elsewhere, a class would be an even better choice, as you could include more data. But if you are certain you will only want the name of the movie, you could just do this.